# Laravel: how to do identity number shouldn't be is same even with others in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel

good evening. Currently i facing issue in saving identity number for a person. Each person should different identity number. If the identify number same means the data shouldn't save but in my case the data saving even though having same data. Anyone can help in this?

check the data exists or not

```
  public function check_child_birth_cert(){ 

        if(Child::where('child_birth_certificate_no')
                ->exists()){
           return "exist";
        }else{                                                                    
           return "not exist";
        }
    }
```

creating data

```
'child_data.child_birth_certificate_no':function(){
                axios.get('check_child_birth_cert/'+ this.pros.child_birth_cert)
                    .then(reponse =>{
                        this.child_birth_certificate_no=reponse.data;
                    })
            }
```

call the function repo to controller

```
public function getchildBirth_cert(Request $request){

        $this->childRepository->check_child_birth_cert($request->all());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this could look a bit more like this:

```php
public function child_birth_cert_exists($child_birth_cert_no) { 

        if(Child::where('child_birth_certificate_no', '=', $child_birth_cert_no)
                ->exists()){
           return true;
        }else{                                                                    
           return false;
        }
    }
```

As already prepared in your JS-call, you can bind a parameter to a route.
So your route would look like this:

```php
Route::post('check_child_birth_cert/{child_birth_cert_no}', 'ChildBirthController@getchildBirth_cert');
```

Then the route parameter is automatically injected within your controller method.

```php
# ChildBirthController
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
public function getchildBirth_cert(Request $request, $child_birth_cert_no) {

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'center_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        \Session::flash('errors', $validation->errors()->toArray());
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    $this->childRepository->check_child_birth_cert($request->all(), $child_birth_cert_no);

    }
```

See here for the parameter binding for routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

**EDIT 1:**
I updated the code samples above.
Sorry, I've seen I made a mistake here. You already sent all the request data into the `check_child_birth_cert`-method.
Generally, if there is a field within your request you can access it via these ways (I missed at least one for sure...):

> - Input::all()
> - $request->get('key') for GET-parameters
> - $request->post('key') for POST-parameters
> - $request->all() for both GET an POST

Using validation as shown helps you to get rid of the `if`-statements and to make sure all data is present the way you need it. You can also extract all the errors from the validation and put them into your session. After that, they will be available in your view-file to be iterated and displayed. This is just a quick example. It would be better to separate the validation from the actual controller into another class OR, even better, using Formrequests (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)

The problem with your example is that you're not sending any POST or GET parameters as far as I understand your JS-code. You just call a GET-route with this route parameter but this is not a real GET-parameter. Do not mix them but rather use a post-route and send them as post-parameters. Route parameters, on the other hand, can help to structurize your routing a bit. But it's dangerous to not get into trouble of not exactly knowing what kind of route is called at a certain point in your app OR you end up with routes meant to be different but as they have the same structure of parts (delimited by "/") the first one matches in your routes-file will be used and maybe not the one you suppose to use.

Consider also the following points:

> - do not send data as a route parameter if it is just any value. It should have an unerring reference to your application data. For example, you can say `/users/{id}` where `{id}` represents the id of a user model in your database. If there is any chance one could access data which he or she is not allowed to see via a route parameter, better pack this route behind at least authentication or even better also authorization.
> - validate your request if it contains any data you will use in your app. The validation of Laravel also sanitizes the data so SQL-injection is no longer your main concern (but it should be in the back of your head).

If you need more values in your called method, you have to request your route with those values as (for my opinion best option) POST.
I don't really understand what you mean with having the same value for `child_birth_certificate_no` and `centre_id`. Could you explain that?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It's working for me. If i want to add centre_id in my if statement hw? ```public function check_child_birth_cert(){ 

        if($request && $request->get('centre_id')){

        if(Child::where('child_birth_certificate_no', '=', $child_birth_cert_no)
                ->exists()){
           return "exist";
        }else{                                                                    
           return "not exist";
        }
    }
}
``` 
is it correct. Can help you me on this?

Comment: It's like this one centre can't have same child_birth_cert_no? How i will do that? @Danaq

Comment: @NavanithaMoorthy I edited my answer with more detail.
If you need more values in your called method, you have to request your route with those values as (for my opinion best option) POST.  
I don't really understand what you mean with having the same value for ```child_birth_certificate_no``` and ```centre_id```. Could you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Check Laravel dock https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses.
You wrote `where` statement without option, where column `child_birth_certificate_no` what? Maybe equals to something? ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way in handling this is by adding the unique constraint to you child migration file

```
$table->string('child_birth_certificate_no')->unique()
```

That way you can prevent the no repeating child_birth_certificate_no will be saved into database.

Comment: can use laravel unique validations with condition rt